# Console.log shows correct value but return shows unresolved promise

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise

I have a library method that returns the location of the user's device, pseudo-code below.

The puzzle is that the `console.log` logs the correct value (in this case a string) whereas the return returns an unresolved promise object (this: `{"_U": 0, "_V": 0, "_W": null, "_X": null}`).

Additionally, the return appears to trigger before the log.

I've no idea why this is happening but I need the return to return the correct, string, value also. Any thoughts?

```js
export const foo = async () => {
  const bar = await Library.method(options);
  console.log(bar);
  return bar;
};
```

Comment: Are you also awaiting the call to `foo` because it will return a promise?

Comment: *"the return returns an unresolved promise object"* - That's exactly what an `async` function always returns.

Comment: Read the [documentation](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function). This code can be rewritten as `export const foo = Library.method.bind(Library, options);` if you no longer need the `console.log`.

Comment: You forgot to `await foo()` to get the result.